# I receive a file not found exception when trying to connect to google maps api

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I am building a feature in an android app which uses the current location of the user to look for nearby places specified by the type of thing the user is searching for. I am using the dependencies `play-services-maps:17.0.1` & `play-services-location:18.0.0` to find these nearby places.

In the `onCreate()` is where I successfully get the longitude & latitude of the user as well as display to the user the map. The user can pick what they want from the drop-down menu, once the find button is clicked a string called `url` is created holding `https://maps.google.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=51.5205959,-0.0629923&radius=5000&type=hospital&sensor=true&key=YOUR_API_KEY`

Than Async task `execute()` is called passing in the `url` as the parameter, the background thread runs the `downloadUrl()` which is supposed to connect the app to the URL link however I receive a `file not found exception` because the URL does not exist. I don't have much experience using the maps API so I don't know why I am receiving a file not found exception.

I have tried changing the URL link to `https://maps.google.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=51.5205933,-0.06276423&radius=5000&type=hospital&sensor=true&key=YOUR_API_KEY` but this does not help as I than don't even recieve the current longitude & latitude of the user because I don't recieve a `location` object from the `FusedLocationProviderClient` object. The api key I received from the google cloud console has Google maps API enabled.

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

GoogleMap map;
Spinner spinner;
Button btnFind;
SupportMapFragment supportMapFragment;
FusedLocationProviderClient fusedLocationProviderClient;
double currentLat = 0;
double currentLong = 0;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    spinner = findViewById(R.id.sp_type);
    btnFind = findViewById(R.id.bt_find);
    supportMapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.google_map);

    final String[] placeTypeList = {"atm", "bank", "hospital", "movie_theater", "restaurant"};
    String[] placeNameList = {"ATM", "Bank", "Hospital", "Movie Theater", "Restaurant"};

    spinner.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, placeNameList));

    fusedLocationProviderClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);

    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        getCurrentLocation();
    }else{

        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, 44);
    }

    btnFind.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            int i = spinner.getSelectedItemPosition();
            String url = "https://maps.google.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?" +
                    "location=" + currentLat + "," + currentLong +
                    "&radius=5000" + "&type=" + placeTypeList[i] +
                    "&sensor=true" + "&key=" + getResources().getString(R.string.google_map_key);

            new PlaceTask().execute(url);
        }

    });

}

public void getCurrentLocation() {

    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        return;
    }

    Task<Location> task = fusedLocationProviderClient.getLastLocation();

    task.addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Location>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Location location) {

                if(location != null){

                    currentLat = location.getLatitude();
                    currentLong = location.getLongitude();

                    supportMapFragment.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onMapReady(@NonNull GoogleMap googleMap) {

                            map = googleMap;

                            map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(currentLat, currentLong), 10));

                        }
                    });
                }
        }
    });
}

private class PlaceTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {


    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {

        String data = null;

        try {

            data = downloadUrl(strings[0]);
        }catch(IOException e){

            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return data;
    }

    private String downloadUrl(String string) throws IOException {

        URL url = new URL(string);

        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        connection.connect();

        InputStream stream = connection.getInputStream();

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));

        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

        String line = "";

        while((line = reader.readLine()) != null){

            builder.append(line);
        }

        String data = builder.toString();
        reader.close();

        return data;
    }
}
```

Comment: You posted twice the same url as far as i can see.

Comment: Everybody can execute those urls to test them. You dont need a location privider to test such an url. Just fill in latitude and longitude.

Comment: you do not need to write connection.connect();  in downloadUrl() otherwise your code is right just check URL.